# Tkinter Python 3 reuse table functionality to put all the header on the left and all the values on the right

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this class that give me back a table with header and values under:

```
class table (Frame):
def __init__(self, parent,controller,pagina,search=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    self.pagina=pagina
    self.search=search
    self.CreateUI()
    self.LoadTable()
    self.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))

def fix_result (query_result): #used to fix the query result in a good format for the table
    header=[]
    lines=[]
    i=0
    while i<len(query_result):
        header.append(query_result[i][0])
        lines.append(query_result[i][1:len(query_result[i])])
        i+=1
    return (header,lines)

def CreateUI(self): 
    tv = Treeview(self)
    if self.pagina=='home': #declare the info needed for the home page
        tv.heading("#0", text='ID')
        tv.column("#0", anchor='center',width =(len('ID')+40))
        tv['columns'] = ('Data Scadenza','Ultimo Pagamento','Nome','Cognome' ,'Telefono' ,'Cellulare' ,'Email')

    elif self.pagina=='user_info': # declare the info needed for the user page
        tv.heading("#0", text='ID')
        tv.column("#0", anchor='center',width =(len('ID')+40))
        tv['columns'] = ('Nome' ,'Cognome' ,'Nascita' ,'Codicefiscale' ,'Indirizzo' ,'Citta' ,'Provincia' ,'Telefono' ,'Cellulare' ,'Email')
    i=0
    while i<len (tv['columns']):
        tv.heading(tv['columns'][i],text=tv['columns'][i])
        ################ establish the width of the column based
        if tv['columns'][i]=='Data Nascita' or tv['columns'][i]=='Telefono' or tv['columns'][i]=='Cellulare' or tv['columns'][i]=='Costo Iscr.' or tv['columns'][i]=='Data Corso' or tv['columns'][i]=='Prezzo Corso':
            tv.column(tv['columns'][i], anchor='center',width =(len(tv['columns'][i])+70))
        else:
            tv.column(tv['columns'][i], anchor='center',width =(len(tv['columns'][i])+160))
        i+=1
    tv.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))
    self.treeview = tv

def LoadTable(self):
    db=DB()
    if self.pagina=='home': #####create data for the table in case that we are in the home page
        month_ago= date.today() + relativedelta(months=-1)
        month=str(month_ago)
        self.db=DB()
        a=self.db.db_query("select m.id, m.dataiscrizione, m.datapagamento, u.nome, u.cognome, u.telefono, u.cellulare, u.email from membership m join users u on m.id=u.id where m.stato='0' and m.dataiscrizione<'"+month.replace("-", "/")+"' order by m.id")
        self.result=table.fix_result (a)
#a use to be a=[(Value0.1, Value0.2),(Value1.1, Value1.2),...]
#self.result use to be self.result=[(Value0.1,Value1.1,Value2.1),[(Value1.2, Value1.3),(Value2.2, Value2.3),(Value3.2, Value3.3)]]
    elif self.pagina=='user_info' and self.search!=None: #####create data for the table in case that we are in the user page
        a=db.db_query("select * from users where id='"+str(self.search)+"'")
        self.result=table.fix_result (a)
    i=0
    while i<len(self.result[0]): #introduce values in the table
        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=str(self.result[0][i]), values=(self.result[1][i]))
        i+=1
```

I'd like to re-use this functionality when the self.pagina=='user_info'; in this moment is working but create a table of this form:

```
Header1 | Header2 | Header3 |.....
---------------------------- ..... 
Value0.1| Value0.2| Value0.3|..... 
Value1.1| Value1.2| Value1.3|.....
```

What I want is that in case that self.pagina=='home', the table still in this way, but in case that self.pagina=='user_info' I know that we have just 1 set of Value so I'd like to have:

```
Header1| Value0.1
Header2| Value0.2
Header3| Value0.3
Header4| Value0.4
................
```

In both case I have a result like this one, but in the second one I have every time just one row and for this reason I wanted a vertical table!

[image]

I try different things with this code but I couldn't re-use the same functionality but I had to write a new one.... Is there some way just to invert the table?

Comment: the indentation doesn't quite look right. The first two lines are at the same indentation level.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley I think that indentation is correct :S maybe when I copy the code here I made a mistake but the code it'w working, I answer my question with a screenshot of what my code produce. Thanks so much

Comment: @clearly it's not correct. Look at the question, you will see the first two lines have exactly the same indentation. It doesn't matter what the code looks like on your machine, all we have to go on is what you posted in the question.

Comment: BTW: instead of `[1:len(query_result[i])]` you can use `[1:]`

Comment: BTW: to make code more readable we use `CamelCase` names only for classes - ie. `Frame`, `Treeview` or `class Table` , and `lower_case` names for methods/functions/variables - ie. `load_table`, `create_ui` - [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: table can't be invert - you have to invert data before you use with table.